# Finding a linear transformation such that $T^{3} = T $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to show that there exists a linear transformation such that

$T^{3} = T $

i can see that from here that T has eigen values $0.1.-1$ .But how do i find linear transformation .Also for v and q be linearly independent vectors .this linear transformation should satisfy $Tv=q $ .Help will be appreciated .Thanks

Comment: Any diagonalizable matrix with eigenvalues $0,1,-1$ will satisfy $T^3=T$. I don't understand your additional condition.

Comment: How about the identity? Or a rotation by 120°?

Comment: @HenningMakholm but eigen values of identity is 1 only

Comment: @tomb_raider: So what? It still satisfies $I^3=I$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm but it will not satisfy $Tv=q$ as there will be $Tv=v$ .

Comment: then you need to ask your questions better and more clearly.  If you can't ask your question properly, you probably haven't put enough time in thinking about the problem anyway.

Comment: @hmakholmleftoverMonica (to your first comment above), old thread, but it must be a typo for $180^\circ$. (A rotation by $120^\circ$ has some imaginary eigenvalues; the three solutions of $\lambda^3=\lambda$ are real.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

Define
$T:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ by $T(1,0,0)=0;T(0,1,0)=(0,1,0);T(0,0,1)=(0,0,-1)$

NOTE:So the transformation becomes $T(c_1,c_2,c_3)=(0,c_2,-c_3)$

Comment: Do i have to find explicit expression for T here and then check whether it satisfies $T^{3} = T $

Comment: you can do it if you wish.But is it not clear from here?@tomb_raider

Comment: i have added a note also